# Not a proper JSON when making a post request

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, request, geoserver

I get a JSON related err when making a post request to geoserver rest api. The documentation of the api is http://docs.geoserver.org/api/#/1.0.0/featuretypes.yaml. The post request I make is

```
handler: function(request, reply) {
          var layerDef = JSON.stringify({
            "namespace": {
              "name": "u77211780_55d2_11e7_96bc_d1171b78c7a0",
              "href": "http://192.168.0.30:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/wfsresult/datastores/WFSSourceResult/featuretypes/u77211780_55d2_11e7_96bc_d1171b78c7a0.json"
            }
          });
          Request('http://192.168.0.30:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/wfsresult/datastores/WFSSourceResult/featuretypes.json',{
            method: 'POST',
            auth: auth,
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            featureType: layerDef
          })
          .on('response', (err, response, body) => {
            console.log(layerDef);
            if(err) {
              reply(err);
            } else {
              reply(body);
            }
          });
        }
```

it returns this issue: : `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of`

I think I have a proper json defined and stringify it correctly. Why it is returning the issue?

Comment: Please Can you try removing the quotes on the key of the json?

Comment: @PaulOkeke That would make no difference....

Comment: What's with the `featureType` property?  I'd imagine it should be a data property of some kind?

Comment: put `layerDef` on a property called 'body' instead of 'featureType'.  You need to send the JSON as the body of the POST request.  'featureType' is not a configuration option for an HTTP request

Comment: Thank you guys! I thought featureType can automatically be treated as body. After change featureType to body and set featureType as top level in the json, it works!